# Set the style of the ComboBoxItems for one combobox but not another?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a style that looks like this:

```
var comboBoxItemStyle = new Style(typeof(ComboBoxItem));
comboBoxItemStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ComboBoxItem.PreviewMouseDownEvent,
                          new MouseButtonEventHandler(OnMyComboItemMouseDown)));

comboBoxItemStyle.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ComboBoxItem.PreviewKeyDownEvent, 
                          new KeyEventHandler(OnMyComboItemPreviewKeyDown)));
```

The next thing I do is this:

```
Resources.Add(typeof(ComboBoxItem), comboBoxItemStyle);
```

But that adds this style to all comboboxes.

Say I have two ComboBoxes:

```
 ComboBox myComboBox = new ComboBox();
 ComboBox someOneElsesComboBox = new ComboBox();
```

**How can I apply this style to just `MyComboBox`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out as I hit "save"

```
myComboBox.Resources.Add(typeof(ComboBoxItem), comboBoxItemStyle);
```